# Passing data from external js file to vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vue-component

I'm trying to pass data from external `data.js` file to the component so that it can be used in it.
However I'm getting error that the data is not defined.

Here is my data.js file

```
const data = [
  {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        type: "boxplot",
        inverted: true,
        height: 200
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Observations",
          data: [[100, 221, 250, 300, 411]]
        },
        {
          name: "Company name",
          color: "yellow",
          type: "scatter",
          data: [[0, 200]],
          marker: {
            fillColor: "yellow",
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: "yellow"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    chartOptions2: {
      chart: {
        type: "boxplot",
        inverted: true,
        height: 200
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Observations",
          data: [[120, 231, 222, 320, 321]]
        },
        {
          name: "Company name 2",
          color: "yellow",
          type: "scatter",
          data: [[0, 210]],
          marker: {
            fillColor: "yellow",
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: "yellow"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

export default data;
```

And here is the component where I need to use data:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highcharts class="hc" :options="chartOptions" ref="chart"></highcharts>
    <highcharts class="hc" :options="chartOptions2" ref="chart"></highcharts>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import data from "./data.js";

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can also try this on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-oijx0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the key/value pair as follows :

```
 data() {
    return {
     charts:data
    };
  },
```

and in the template access the items of the `charts` array :

```
<div>
    <highcharts class="hc" :options="charts[0].chartOptions" ref="chart"></highcharts>
    <highcharts class="hc" :options="charts[1].chartOptions2" ref="chart2"></highcharts>
  </div>
```

[image: Edit Highcharts Vue Demo]

Answer (score 3):

Convert your data.js to object (now it's an array):

```js
const data = {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        type: "boxplot",
        inverted: true,
        height: 200
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Observations",
          data: [[100, 221, 250, 300, 411]]
        },
        {
          name: "Company name",
          color: "yellow",
          type: "scatter",
          data: [[0, 200]],
          marker: {
            fillColor: "yellow",
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: "yellow"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    chartOptions2: {
      chart: {
        type: "boxplot",
        inverted: true,
        height: 200
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Observations",
          data: [[120, 231, 222, 320, 321]]
        },
        {
          name: "Company name 2",
          color: "yellow",
          type: "scatter",
          data: [[0, 210]],
          marker: {
            fillColor: "yellow",
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: "yellow"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
export default data;
```

Then in your component:

```js
import data from "./data.js";

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      chartOptions: data.chartOptions,
      chartOptions2: data.chartOptions2,
    }
  }
};
```